# How can i get non String Array field from SQL query with multiple rows

Tags: java, sql, arrays, hsqldb

I have SQL (HSQLDB) table with **VALS DOUBLE ARRAY[2000]** field
I use query that returns multiple rows with VALS field
If i try to get array as

```
Array array = rs.getArray("VALS");
Double[] vals = (Double[]) array.getArray();
```

i get

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Double;
```

I can get values with double conversion from Object to String and then parsing String to Double like:

```
List<Double> values = new ArrayList<Double>();
for (Object o: (Object[])array.getArray()) {
    values.add(Double.parseDouble(o.toString()));
}
```

But it looks like heavy overhead

Is there any way to get digits from Array SQL field without String conversion or multiple single-row queries? In debugger rs.getArray() shows me a perfect JDBCArray of digital values `ARRAY[0.0E0,0.0E0,0.0E0,0.0E0,0.0E0 .... ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to convert to String and back. Just cast:

```
List<Double> values = new ArrayList<Double>(); 
for (Object o: (Object[])array.getArray()) {
    values.add((Double) o); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below:

`Double[] vals = Arrays.stream(array.getArray())
                        .map(Double::valueOf)
                        .toArray(Double[]::new);`

Comment: Unresolved compilation problem: The method stream(T[]) in the type Arrays is not applicable for the arguments (Object) If i add cast to Double[] i get the same exception as in the beginning, if i cast to Object[] than i get Unresolved compilation problems: 
 Cannot infer type argument(s) for <R> map(Function<? super T,? extends R>)